# Microk8s Raspberry Pi 4 cluster

Tags: raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, raspberry-pi4, microk8s

I am trying to setup a Microk8s Raspberry Pi 4 cluster with 6 Raspberry Pi SoC Ubuntu 20.4 servers. At first it was working after some restart none of the microk8s are working on servers. Getting not running status on microk8s status command. It was working fine on first installation. But now it is not working even after trying to start with microk8s start, it will give started but still get not running status. Tried microk8s inspect. It shows all services are running and there is no error.

Could somebody help to find out what is going wrong with Raspberry Pi 4 for the microk8s cluster?
Find inspection report of microk8s on following link - [Microk8s inspection report](http://netg9.com/inspection-report-20210312_174617.tar.gz).

Comment: You're going to need to find a better way to share that inspection report. Nobody is going to follow the link, click a button, enter a captcha, click another button...etc. Generally, we expect the question to contain all the necessary information without depending on external links, because if/when that external link expires, the question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: uploaded to a new server with direct access. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by re-installing the cluster from scratch as there was some overlapping remove-node happened, cluster turned inoperable. Now everything working fine.

So we need to do one thing (configuration change) at a time in a microk8s cluster and give a few minutes for the cluster to reconfigure itself with new configuration will save the cluster from crushing itself.